# How to save Push Notification Data in SharedPreferences and display in RecyclerView

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have created an application that receives push notifications from PushBots.

I am successfully receiving the Push Notifications but I want to store the push data in SharedPreferences and display it another activity containing a RecyclerView.

I know Content providers is a better approach, but I want to stick with SharedPreferences as of now.

Here's my custom **Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class customHandler extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "customHandler";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "action=" + action);
        // Handle Push Message when opened
        if (action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_OPEN)) {
            //Check for Pushbots Instance
            Pushbots pushInstance = Pushbots.sharedInstance();
            if(!pushInstance.isInitialized()){
                Log.d("Initializing Pushbots.");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(context.getApplicationContext());
            }

            //Clear Notification array
            if(PBNotificationIntent.notificationsArray != null){
                PBNotificationIntent.notificationsArray = null;
            }

            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_OPEN);
            Log.w(TAG, "User clicked notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));

            //Report Opened Push Notification to Pushbots
            if(Pushbots.sharedInstance().isAnalyticsEnabled()){
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().reportPushOpened( (String) PushdataOpen.get("PUSHANALYTICS"));
            }

            //Start Main Activity On CLicking Notification
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            resultIntent.putExtras(intent.getBundleExtra("pushData"));
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().startActivity(resultIntent);

            // Handle Push Message when received
        }else if(action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE)){
            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE);
            Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in which part are you facing the problem?

Comment: Unable to save the string in sharedpreferences, also in my fragment where I populate the RecyclerView I am unable to get access to the sharedpreferences file

Comment: added my answer below. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom PushData class and use Gson library to save as a string your data.

Here is a clean [example](http://moonlightbox.logdown.com/posts/2015/04/14/android-store-object-in-shared-preferences)

Comment: My data is plain text

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
public void addNotification(String notification) {
    // get old notifications
    String oldNotifications = getNotifications();
    if (oldNotifications != null) {
        oldNotifications += "|" + notification;
    } else {
        oldNotifications = notification;
    }
    editor.putString(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, oldNotifications);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getNotifications() {
    return pref.getString(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, null);
}
```

and get it

```
String oldNotification = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getNotifications();
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(oldNotification.split("\\|"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For putting string in `SharedPreferences` :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

For getting shared preferences in fragment :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString(key, "default value");
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Initialize Shared Preference variables in `onReceive` method like below ,

```
 SharedPreferences prf = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prf.edit();
```

**2.** Save Push Message to shared preference when receive,

```
          ................
          ................

     // Handle Push Message when received
            }else if(action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE))
               {
                HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE);
                Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));

                String message=(String) PushdataOpen.get("message");
                editor.putString("push_message", message);
                editor.commit();
            }
```

**3.** Get saved push message from shared preference for display,

```
SharedPreferences prf = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String message=prf.getString("push_message", "");
```